# How to use inner join in controller and pass result to blade template

Tags: laravel-5, inner-join, laravel-blade

```
public function index()
{
    $lesson= DB::table('lessons')
        ->select('long_text')
        ->join('courses', 'courses.lesson_id', '=', 'lessons.id')
        ->where('courses.title', $courses)
        ->get();

    return view(lesson.index);
}
```

in my blade

```
<ul>
    <li style="text-transform: uppercase;"> {{$courses->title}} </li>
</ul>
```

On clicking the title it should show me the lesson from that course

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the data to your blade as:

```
public function index()
{
    $course= DB::table('lessons')
        ->select('long_text')
        ->join('courses', 'courses.lesson_id', '=', 'lessons.id')
        ->where('courses.title', $courses)
        ->get();

    return view(lesson.index, compact('course'));
}
```

Then you can use the following code snippet to display the contents for the course title

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Course title
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        All the details that you need to display of that course.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```